# Set the content of a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, textblock

Say I have a `TextBlock` that looks like this:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" >
    Text in <Run Foreground="Red">red</Run> and <Run Foreground="Red">more</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

That works fine and the text is shown in red as you think it would.  However, in my real example this text:

```
 Text in <Run Foreground="Red">red</Run> and <Run Foreground="Red">more</Run>
```

Comes from a service call. (Including the  tags.)

**Is there a way to supply this text to the `TextBlock` at runtime?**

Comment: This is why I asked you to explain how you were going to mark the red parts. :)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd - Yeah, I did not realize at the TextBlock could not take the string as is.  Really, I can use any kind of markup.  (I just the added "Run" tags in a few minutes ago.)  I just need any way to have the server markup the text so it can be displayed without parsing on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you have to convert all the input text into `Inlines` collection (of type `TextElementCollection`). However doing so requires parsing the input text yourself which is not easy. So why not use the existing parser supported by `XamlReader`. By using this class, you can parse a XAML code to get an instance of a `TextBlock` from which you can get the `Inlines` collection and add that for your actual `TextBlock`. Here is the code:

```
var text = "<TextBlock>Text in <Run Foreground=\"Red\">red</Run> and <Run Foreground=\"Red\">more</Run></TextBlock>";
var pc = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
pc.XmlnsDictionary[""] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
pc.XmlnsDictionary["x"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
var tbl = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(text, pc) as TextBlock;
yourTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();            
yourTextBlock.Inlines.AddRange(tbl.Inlines.ToList());
```

Your actual input text should be wrapped in the pair `<TextBlock>` & `</TextBlock>` before being used by the next code.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I made it into a control and can bind my text to it now.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would post the control that I made from King Kong's answer.  (Just in case it is useful to someone else.)

```
public class FormatBindableTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    private static readonly ParserContext parserContext;

    static FormatBindableTextBlock()
    {
        parserContext = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
        parserContext.XmlnsDictionary[""] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
        parserContext.XmlnsDictionary["x"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FormattedContent", typeof(string), typeof(FormatBindableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnFormattedContentPropertyChanged));

    public string FormattedContent
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FormattedContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FormattedContentProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnFormattedContentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormatBindableTextBlock textBlock = sender as FormatBindableTextBlock;

        if (textBlock == null)
            return;

        string newFormattedContent = e.NewValue as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newFormattedContent)) 
            newFormattedContent = "";

        newFormattedContent = "<TextBlock>" + newFormattedContent + "</TextBlock>";

        TextBlock tbl = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(newFormattedContent, parserContext) as TextBlock;
        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(tbl.Inlines.ToList());

    }

}
```